# Rocket Curvature in C++ SDL game

Tags: c++, math, sdl, physics, game-physics

I am making cabal on C++ using SDL library. Cabal is a game in which a player sits on the bottom of the screen and can only move in x direction. While enemies appear in front and shoot missiles at you. The game is a bit like this.

[image: In game Picture]

I want the rocket to take the trajectory shown in the green. A curved trajectory. However it takes the trajectory which is shown in the red. Keep in mind the player is also moving so trajectory is not fixed.

The code I have implemented so far is this:

```
void Missiles::Move(int playerX)
{

    angle =atan(playerX - X);

    X=X + sin(angle)*2;

}
```

Where PlayerX is the player's X co-ordinates and X is the rocket's X co-ordinates. I have made the Y-coordinates to change at a constant speed, so I have not shown them in the code.

Comment: Should the rocket have an initial velocity and then just fall or should it be more like a seeking missile ? The problem (hence the answer) is absolutely not the same and your question is quite unclear about that.

Comment: Also should the missile be pointing to the player at anytime or should it have some delay to face toward it, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To get aiming angle, it is necessary to take Y-coordinate difference into account

```
angle = atan2(PlayerY - RocketY, PlayerX - RocketX);
```

Another issue  - in reality and in physics rocket velocity is limited. It consists of vertical and horizontal components

```
Vx = V * Cos(angle)
Vy = V * Sin(angle)
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the rocket is fired by the enemies above and it should be coming towards the player on the bottom. The player can only move in x-axis. In your formula, it does not seem that the rocket is following the player's movement?

Comment: Yes, I considered aiming to enemy. Will replace EnemyY,X by PlayerY.X. But what are initial states of rockets ?